# Turing-Shannon connection

Tags: it.information-theory

From Alan Turing we know what we can expect from a computer and from Claude Shannon what we can expect from a communication channel.

Does anyone know any connection between these two theories (namely, Automata Theory and Information Theory) which actually set the theoretical limits of the nowadays information technology era?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to focus your question a little more sharply? What kind of connection do you seek? Which structural features do you want the connection to respect? 

Comment: @Joel: I was in thinking in how the capacity of a channel can be related to the capacity of an automata for accepting a language.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the theoretical limits of the nowadays information technology era"?

Comment: @jc Indeed, information theory on its primal approach was devoted to study the limits of the communication. Moreover, Automata theory is focused on the limits of the computer science. Computers and communication devices are the support of nowadays technological society.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_information_theory

Comment: Good one, but I was looking for more concrete examples.

Comment: Then, mikitov, you might ask a more focussed question to elicit such.  I invite you to read the FAQ and how-to-ask pages for guidance.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.25  

Answer (score 0):

Turing's limit is logic - it speaks about static data if you will. Shannon's has to do with data transmission - movement, so to speak. There is some thought of combining logic with communication in the context of control theory. Turing's and Shannon's theorems appear in hybrid control theory to be precise - the branch that studies dynamic controls together with logic and switching. Nevertheless, they seem to be fundamentally different facts.

Answer (score 0):

Madhu Sudan talked about a strictly related issue.
His talk is online at http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/talks/2011/CommComp-UIUC.ppsx